# Passing HTML5 geolocation data to express server

Tags: javascript, html, express, axios

I am using the HTML5 geolocation api as so.

```
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(patchPosition);
  console.log('location')
    } else {
   console.log('no location');
 }
   }

 function patchPosition(position) {
      axios.post('/user', {
           lat: position.coords.latitude,
           lng: position.coords.longitude
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log("geolocation", res.config.data)
      }).catch( function(error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    }
  })
}


 getLocation();
```

and I am trying to pass the latitude and longitude back to this express route.

```
router.get('/', authHelpers.loginRequired, apiHelpers.getResults, (req, 
res, next) => {
  console.log('places ======>' + res);
  res.render('user/index', {
  user: req.user.dataValues,
places: res.locals.places,
locations: res.locals.locations,
userLat: res.locals.lat,
userLong: res.locals.long
 });

 });
```

After extensive research into this problem, I have not been able to get anything to work. I was initially using googles geolocation api but was only getting the location of the server so I am trying to get the HTML5 one to work. Please help.

Comment: Are you able to get the geolocation data client-side?

Comment: Yes the position.coords.latitude etc. console logs properly.

Comment: It doesn't look like your two routes are matching up. In the first block you're making a `POST` to `/user` and in the second (your route), you're expecting a `GET` to `/`. Have you tried just changing your route to `router.post('/user',...`?

Comment: @kqcef I should have stated in the question that I really need the information for the apiHelpers.getResults function thats being imported and called in the router.get('/', ...)

Comment: Why do you need it in the `.get('/'...` route? It seems like you need the data to be sent to a specific endpoint, not your root index. You can pass the data to your `apiHelpers.getResults` callback in a different route.